# jquery Tree Traversal prev() problem

Tags: jquery, tree-traversal

I like to click a label and check the previous checkbox.
I've tried the next code, but  this is not working. I have tried for 2 hours, but what am i missing?

```
JQUERY

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.namelabel').live('click', function() {
        if ($(this).prev("input:checked").val() != null) {
            $(this).prev("input").removeAttr("checked");
        } else  {
            $(this).prev("input").attr("checked","checked"); 
        }
    });
});

HTML
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="example" /> <img src="image.png" class="modelinfo" /> <label class="namelabel">John Doe</label>
```

Who can help me to solve this question? Many thanks!

p.s. I know i can easy solve this with the `<label for="">` tag, but that is not the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.profilename').live('click', function() {
  var cb = $(this).prevAll(":checkbox:first");
  cb.attr("checked", !cb.is(":checked")); 
});
```

Also, just noticed your class doesn't match, in your html it's `namelabel` but in your jQuery it's `profilename`, is it a different example or should they match up?

Comment: Thanks, that works fine!
Only i made a changement into the code. Between the INPUT and the LABEL i put a IMG, and now your method does not function anymore. I think i misunderstand the prev() function of jquery... I thought prev() find the first previously type you defined, but it isn't?

Comment: I think i understand now. Prev() looks only if it's about the previous element, that need to match.

So for my example HTML i need the next code:

 $('.namelabel').live('click', function() {
     if ($(this).prev('img').prev("input").is(":checked")) {
         $(this).prev('img').prev("input").attr("checked", false); 
     } else  { 
         $(this).prev('img').prev("input").attr("checked", true); 
     }
 });

Comment: @Guido Lemmens - Updated the answer for this :)  `.prev()` finds the immediately previous element (if it matches, otherwise nothing), whereas `.prevAll()` finds all previous siblings, then filter for the first one you find.  I simplified the code overall as well to do the same thing much faster.